# R plot without showing the graphic window

Tags: r, plot

I need to store a plot object in a variable. I know that I can do:

```
plot(rnorm(10))
obj = recordPlot()
replayPlot(obj)
```

But I don't want to show the graphic window. So I'm trying to do this, but with no success until now.

```
win.metafile()
plot(rnorm(10))
obj = recordPlot()
dev.off()
replayPlot(obj) # it shows a null plot
```

Well, probably because when I'm doing `obj = recordPlot()` the plot isn't ready yet.

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue. Calling `replayPlot(obj)` shows the plot fine for me.

Comment: You can do that with `ggplot2`.

Comment: Maybe we can help better if you tell us why you need to store the plot in a variable.

Comment: Mattrition, indeed for the first code. But in the second it shows a null plot.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From `?recordPlot`:

```
The displaylist can be turned on and off using dev.control. 
Initially recording is on for screen devices, and off for print devices.
```

So you need to turn on the displaylist if you want to record a plot writing to file:

```
win.metafile()
dev.control('enable') # enable display list
plot(rnorm(10))
obj = recordPlot()
dev.off()
replayPlot(obj)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do that easily with `ggplot2`:

```
require(ggplot2)
data = data.frame(x = 1:100, y = rnorm(100))
p = ggplot(data) + geom_point(aes(x, y)) + theme_classic()
print(p) # this show the plot
```

Comment: Thanks Fernando. It worked. But I have a pretty high number of plots  at the moment and I need to keep with the standard plots. However, as soon as I get, I will begin the transition of all my plots to ggplot :)

Comment: It's easy to make it look like a standard plot, just check the examples with `?theme`.